# Sql server name aliases in Windows Azure

Tags: sql, azure, ssms

I use Management Studio to connect with SQL Azure database. To connect I entered server name in this format, but this name is not user friendly. (When I have many servers I'm confused)

```
m24*****i.database.windows.net
```

Is it possible to change this name to more readable or save connection data in any connection manager in ManagementStudio. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Configuration Manager to create aliases for your server's name.

Create aliases in the two node of SQL Server Configuration Manager：

1.SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration\Aliases node

2.SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32bit)\Aliases node

**Example**

```
Alias Name：YourAliasName
Port No：1433
Protocol：TCP/IP
Server：m24*****i.database.windows.net
```